# How can I style a certain element only when wptouch is active?

Tags: twitter, css, plugin-wptouch

I just installed the [wptouch plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) for auto-styling my blog in mobile devices. How can I style a certain element on my page to be hidden when this view is active?

I.e., in particular, on my blog [Under My Hat](http://undermhyhat.org), I have a [WP Follow Me plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-followme/) which behaves rather annoyingly on mobile devices, which is why I'd like to hide it. But other elements are custom tables and source code examples that I would like to style differently.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to *intrude* myself into WPTouch until I buy a licence :)

Better than simply hiding other plugins is disabling everything you can of it.
And the visitor gain less (and unnecessary) elements to load in their device.

The `insert_scripts` is pretty straight forward, adjust to your needs.

The `remove_scripts` I did from a fast analysis of [Follow Me code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-followme/trunk/followme.php).
To check if you really got rid of the plugin scripts, test using Safari with its Activity Monitor and User Agent simulator (it's perfect on Macs, donnow in Wins).

> **edit**: my original/working script have these calls inside the `remove_scripts`:
>
> ```
> remove_action('wp_head', 'add_css');
> wp_deregister_script( 'jqplot' );
> ```
>
> And right now, re-reading this answer, I think that `add_action('wp_head','function');` being used to `remove_action('init','function');` **may not be correct**, would be glad to have a peer review...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPTouch Retouch
Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52026/12615
Description: Add custom scripts to enhance WPTouch and remove WP Follow Me scripts
Version: 1.0
*/

add_action('init', 'wpse_52026_process_wptouch');

function wpse_52026_process_wptouch(){
    if (function_exists('bnc_wptouch_is_mobile')) {
        if(bnc_wptouch_is_mobile()) {
            add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_52026_remove_plugin_scripts', 1);
            add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_52026_insert_wptouch_scripts');
        }
    } 
}

function wpse_52026_remove_plugin_scripts() {
    remove_action('init', 'wp_followme_scripts');
    remove_action('init', 'followme_admin_warnings');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_followme_css');
    remove_action('get_footer', 'show_followme');
    //wp_deregister_script( 'if-there-were-a-registered-script' ); 
}

function wpse_52026_insert_wptouch_scripts() {
    $today = 'Valencia : Spain : '. date("d/m/Y");
    echo <<<HTML
    <style type="text/css">
        body {background:url('http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/pattern.png') fixed !important;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $("div.content").prepend('<div style="margin-left: 13px;"><h4>Site Description</h4><small>{$today}</small></div>');
    });
    </script>
HTML;
}
```

Attention to the [PHP Heredoc syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581315/php-heredoc-string-rules) `<<<HTML`

**[important update]**
When first answered, I forgot an essential part: **this has to run as a plugin**.

Obviously, putting the code into the desktop theme `functions.php` file doesn't do the job. And hacking other plugins is kind of *pita*: at each update you have to re-hack...

**[references on how to remove other plugins' styles and scripts]**
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40833/12615
[Is it possible to stop selected plugins from loading on certain template pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/24710/12615)
[How to dequeue a script?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1535/12615)
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27983/12615
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13331/12615

Comment: Excellent, I wished I could give you a double upvote for the Safari-hint. One question though, where would I place this script? If in the Follow-me code, would WPTouch already be loaded? Or when in the WPTouch code, would the follow-me already be loaded? Or is there some general post-addscripts hook I can use?

Comment: Sorry mate, I forgot an essential part of the code :/ It has to run as a plugin. I'll update my answer with a plugin header and this extra info.